# Django queryset reverse foreign key for json link

Tags: python, json, django, api, django-queryset

I using python and Django framework and have two tables with foreign key relationship and I want to create a some query where  the result includes fields from second table using foreign key to export that result in some JSON api.

I would like to create a query in table work but in the results I would like to add the fields from table abilities based on foreign key

models.py

```
class work(models.Model):
    field_0 = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)
    field_1=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)



class abilities(models.Model):
    field_3 = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)
    field_4=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)
    field_5=models.CharField(max_length=254,blank=True, null=True)
    field_fk= models.ForeignKey('work', blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py

```
def work_json(request):
    work_se=serialize('json',work.objects.all())
    return HttpResponse(work_se,content_type='json')
```

json result where I take from my view :

```
[
{
"model": "mymodel",
"pk": 1,
"fields": {
"field_0": "some value",
"field_1": "some value field 1",
}
}
……… next object
]
```

json result where I need(with fields from table where have field_fk 1)

```
[
{
"model": "mymodel",
"pk": 1,
"fields": {
"field_0": "some value",
"field_1": "some value field 1",

"field_3": "some value field 3",
"field_4": "some value field 4",
"field_5": "some value field 5",

}
……… next object
]
```

any idea how to do that ?

thanks

Comment: it's really not clear what you're asking

Comment: @Rich I would like to create a query in table work but in the results I would like to add the fields from table abilities based on the fk

Answer (score 0):

Flat inclusion as you proposed would only work if you had a one-to-one relationship between the two models. With a one-to-many relationship, you need to nest the `Abilities` objects in your `Work` objects (see [Python naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) BTW). The [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization) helps in doing this, giving you something like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "field_0": "data in field_0",
    "abilities_set": {
        {
            "id": 1,
            "field_3": "data in field_3",
            "field_4": "data in field_4",
            "field_5": "data in field_5"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "field_3": "data in field_3",
            "field_4": "data in field_4",
            "field_5": "data in field_5"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your posted code, the relationship between `Work` and `Abilities` is a one-to-many relationship already.

Comment: IOW, no need to change anything in the models as posted (except perhaps the lowercase name :)).

Answer (score 0):

```
class ResourceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Resource
        fields = '__all__'


class SiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    resources = ResourceSerializer(read_only=True, many=True) # resource is the foreign key in site

    class Meta:
        model = Site
        fields = '__all__'


def all_sites(request):
    sites = Site.objects.all()
    serialize = SiteSerializer(sites, many=True)

    main = {'status': True, 'msg': 'OK', 'sites': serialize.data}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(main), content_type='application/json')
```

Create model serializers for both the models,the `serialize.data` in views contains the dictionary that you want to access as a dictionary, is this what you want?

Comment: and in views where I need to write?

Comment: actually all this is in the views

Comment: those serializers are called model serializer since they reference a model from your models.py,

Comment: ok because many users use additional  Serializer.py , I am not sure but I need to test it this